# Sending calender(google,apple etc) over mail in react

Tags: reactjs

Hello i am trying to build a react js app where i need to send the invitation of the event through mail and mark it on the client's calender.I am not sure what to do or where to start from.Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: if I were you start with the developer documentation of the calendar that you are trying to use. you must understand that react is mainly about building UI. everything under the hood still happens with javascript or a javascript library of your chioce. the calendar you are using may also have their own library that you can integrate with your react app.

Comment: okay thnak for the advice